# Accepting all vectors of matrices of numbers as a function argument in Julia

Tags: types, type-conversion, julia

I'm attempting to write a function that takes a vector of matrices and calculates their product recursively. The function itself goes something like this:

```
using LinearAlgebra: I

"""
Recursively calculates the product of the matrices in a given vector `V`.
"""
function ∏_(V)
    if length(V) == 1
        return V[1]
    elseif length(V) == 0
        UniformScaling(1)
    else
        V[1] * ∏_(V[2:end])
    end
end
```

This is all fine and dandy, but I would like to limit the types of the input to something like

```
V::Vector{Matrix{Number}} ,
```

where `Number` could be any field element (an integer, a rational or a complex number). How might I achieve this with Julia's type annotations? I know of the subtype operator `<:`, but writing

```
V::Vector{Matrix{<:Number}}
```

simply produces the error

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching ∏_(::Array{Array{Rational{Int64},2},1})
Closest candidates are:
    ∏_(::Array{Array{var"#s1",2} where var"#s1"<:Number,1})
```

when giving the function an array of rational integer matrices. How might I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `V::Vector{<:Matrix{<:Number}}`

However, you can extend it further to allow more uses, for example

```
V::AbstractVector{<:AbstractMatrix{<:Number}}
V::AbstractVector{<:AbstractMatrix}
V::AbstractVector
V::Any
```

It probably doesn't harm anyone and might allow futures uses you don't even imagine right now

Comment: Another (equivalent) option is to use the `Vector{Matrix{T}} where T <:Number` notation

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's considered poor form to overly restrict input types in Julia. Try to make your type signatures as permissive as you can, and if you do not need to do dispatch (choose between different implementations for different inputs), you should consider not using types at all.

In this case, I would probably just use `V::AbstractVector` and let the elements be "any type that supports multiplication", no reason to even restrict it to `Number`s, imho.

Also, in this case, you can just use `prod`, which does exactly what you want:

```
 ∏_(V) = prod(V)
```

BTW: It's probably better to write `I` or `LinearAlgebra.I`, instead of `UniformScaling(1)`. The `1` argument is an `Int64`, which can cause type promotion, if it operates on matrices of lower integers, like `Int32`.